# How to pass from a component to the parent a radio button choice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to replicate the [parent-child communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) in components. The idea is to have a two-choice component based on radio buttons, reused several times:

```js
Vue.component('chooser', {
  template: '<form> <input type="radio" value="hello" v-model="picked"> Hello<br><input type="radio" value="world" v-model="picked"> World<br></form>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      picked: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    picked: function() {
      this.$emit('picked')
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    first: null,
    second: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <chooser v-model="first"></chooser>
  Here I want to get choice one: {{first}}
  <chooser v-model="second"></chooser>
  Here I want to get choice two: {{second}}
</div>
```

I do not get the information from the component back to the parent, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `$emit` function correctly. To emulate v-model, you should emit an event of type 'input' (first argument) and the corresponding value (second argument).

```js
Vue.component('chooser', {
  template: '<form> <input type="radio" value="hello" v-model="picked"> Hello<br><input type="radio" value="world" v-model="picked"> World<br></form>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      picked: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    picked: function() {
      this.$emit('input', this.picked);
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    first: null,
    second: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <chooser v-model="first"></chooser>
  Here I want to get choice one: {{first}}
  <chooser v-model="second"></chooser>
  Here I want to get choice two: {{second}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed that in the one only place where it is mentioned in the docs I linked (in an example, actually)